# MySQL Server 5.0 command line client failed to open file .sql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to use MySQL command line client to execute a procedure. The procedure `helloworld()` is executing fine in MySQL query browser.

db scheme selected in query browser:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS helloworld$$
CREATE PROCEDURE helloworld()
BEGIN
SELECT 'helloworld';
END$$
```

When I `call helloworld()` it returns helloworld. I am saving the procedure as `helloworld.sql` saved in SQL SCRIPT FILE ANSI .sql in desktop

Now I am trying to access the .sql file  saved in desktop from cmd client giving the password that connects successfully

Now when I type

```
ENTER PASSWORD:******
Your Mysql connection id is 43
Server Vesion 5.5.24

mysql> SOURCE helloworld.sql
ERROR failed to open file helloworld.sql Error 2
```

Should I give the path of the file?

Comment: You basically answered your own question: "*Should I give the path of the file*" - yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

/path/to/file/helloworld.sql:

```sql
USE `yourdb`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `helloworld`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `helloworld`()
BEGIN
  SELECT 'helloworld';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then from the command line try:

```
Your Mysql connection id is 43
Server Vesion 5.5.24

mysql> SOURCE /path/to/file/helloworld.sql
```

Comment: Can you explain please? You just add `USE` statement right?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the solution was in fact to change the ownership of the source file to be the username of the user who was logging into the machine and running the command via the `mysql` terminal.  I am using CentOS Linux with MariaDB/MySQL5.6.

The command that worked to remove the error was: `sudo chown username:username sourcefile.sql`

I also tried changing it to `mysql:mysql` instead of `username:username`, but the error persisted until I used `sudo chown username:username sourcefile.sql`

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem. The solution worked for me is

```
sudo chown root:root /Full/path/to/sqlfile.sql
Sudo su;
mysql -u root -p < /Full/path/to/sqlfile.sql
```

If it helps anyone in future.

Answer (score -1):

It's a file permission issue.

The *mysql process*, *not* the user of the shell running the mysql command interface, needs permission to read the file.

Comment: `source` is a command of the mysql client to (and is executed by that). I don't think the *client program*  will try to read a file on the *server*.

Answer (score -1):

i have also got the same message when i try to do the operation from mysql console but when i open the command prompt and do the same steps its working well not getting any error

```
C:\Users\SubhenduD>cd ../

C:\Users>cd ../

C:\>cd \xampp\mysql\bin


C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u -root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 68
Server version: 5.6.16 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.


mysql> use balticktravels;

mysql> source balticktravels.sql;
```